# Adding user's choices to test results

Tags: php, jquery

This is a little tricky to explain, so bear with me...

I've put together a database-driven test script that works pretty nicely. After a user selects their answers and pushes a submit button, they're forwarded to a page (grade.php) that displays their score.

Beneath the score is a copy of the test they just took, with the correct answers highlighted. I would simply like to modify it so that the answers users chose are also highlighted.

For example, if a user chose answer A, and that's the correct answer, then it might have a yellow background (indicating it's the correct answer) plus a gold star (indicating a user chose that correct answer). If a user chose B, then it might have a black background (indicating it's an incorrect choice), plus it might have an image depicting a checkmark, indicating that the user chose that incorrect answer.

Let's start with the form at the bottom of the test page:

```
<form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
 <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" id="url" />
 <input type="hidden" name="grade" value="<?php echo $grade; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_token']) ? $_POST['user_token'] : '' ; ?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
</form>
```

After clicking submit, we're forwarded to grade.php, which has a switch containing answer keys for various tests. In this example, we took a ten-question quiz identified by its URL - px-intro-4. Here's the answer key:

```
$answers = array(1 => array('D'), 
             2 => array('A'), 
             3 => array('C'), 
             4 => array('A'), 
             5 => array('Libya'), 
             6 => array('B'), 
             7 => array('B'), 
             8 => array('B'), 
             9 => array('C', 'D'), 
             10 => array('D'));
$total = count($answers);
```

Most are multiple choice questions, where users select the one best answer. In this example, they have to type in an answer for #5, and they have to select TWO options (checkboxes) for #9.

If they get every answer correct, echoing var_dump($_POST); displays the following:

```
array(13) { 
    ["q1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "D" } 
    ["q2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } 
    ["q3"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "C" } 
    ["q4"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } 
    ["q5"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Libya" } 
    ["q6"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } 
    ["q7"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } 
    ["q8"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } 
    ["q9"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "C" [1]=> string(1) "D" } 
    ["q10"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "D" } 
    ["PreviousURL"]=> string(25) "http://g1/test/px-intro-4" 
    ["grade"]=> string(147) "
}
```

If they take the test again and miss #9 and don't answer #10 at all, the array changes to this:

```
array(12) { 
    ["q1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "D" } 
    ["q2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } 
    ["q3"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "C" } 
    ["q4"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "A" } 
    ["q5"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "Libya" } 
    ["q6"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } 
    ["q7"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } 
    ["q8"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "B" } 
    ["q9"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "B" [1]=> string(1) "D" } 
    ["PreviousURL"]=> string(25) "http://g1/test/px-intro-4" 
    ["grade"]=> string(147) "
}
```

To make it more clear, imagine the following text on the results page (grade.php):

2. Where do penguins live?

A. Africa

B. Antarctica (yellow background, indicating it's the correct answer + a gold star indicating the user chose this correct answer)

C. France

D. California

My page already displays correct and incorrect answers. Can anyone tell me how to superimpose the USER's CHOICES? I'll probably have to jump through a few hoops to make this work, but if you can just point me in the right direction, then I can play with it and maybe ask some more focused questions.

I should mention that I have a little experience with jQuery, though I'm working primarily with PHP - just in case there's a jQuery solution.

Comment: question is bit unclear and don't know how you are doing it now, but here is how i may do this. use multiple styles like when the user chooses correct answer `style="answer correct_chosen"` and if a user choose wrong answer `style="wrong_answer wrong_chosen"` and a mix of the styles for others. In the styles `answer` should have yellow background `correct_chosen` would have a gold star, `wrong_chosen` would have check and so on....

Comment: Thanks, but I've already designated unique styles. The problem is I know how to "recognize" an answer as correct or incorrect, but I don't know how to also recognize it as "selected" by a user. There may be a really simple solution right under my nose, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: if the choice `q1` refers to question 1 in the answer key you have provided, then you can use the following. what user chose is available in `q1` now remove the `q` and you the answer key. if they match the answer is correct, else wrong.